# JS playing sound on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, audio

I have a simple code for playing a sound effect in JS in an onmouseover event. It works like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sonido=document.getElementById("neonclip");
</script>
<audio preload id="neonclip">
    <source src="http://www.mysite/neon.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

And the onmouseover bit:

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('neonclip').play();"
```

Problem is it works in Firefox/Opera/Chrome but not on IE, I need it to work in all major browsers. I know its a problem with the sound file format, IE can't play .ogg. So I need to add an .mp3 maybe, how should I do it? Adding an If detecting the browser in the script?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516s35/how-to-detect-supported-video-formats-for-the-html5-video-tag

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: I'm testing it on IE 9.0